# Update all clients view on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, using entity framework and I need implement the following:
When one of the users updates a certain view a callback function needs to be called, and refresh the view state for all clients.
For example:

HTML:

```
<label>Number of copies left:</label><span>@item.Amount</span>
<button onclick="buy">Buy</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Home/Buy",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(myParams)  
    });
</script>
```

Contoller:

```
public void Buy()
{
    //Update DB
    //Write callback code
}
```

When any client clicks on the buy button, and the Buy function by the controller is called the @item.Amount needs to be refreshed by all clients according to the updates on the entity.
How do I update the view for all users, and not just the user that bought the product?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

With some usage of Javascript code this should work perfectly in your case

Read [this short tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5) that should be enough in your particular scenario.